# How to encode special characters in HtmlInputText Control in .Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an input control

```
<input id="firstNameField" type="text" runat="server" />
```

And I give it a value server-side

```
firstNameField.Value = "Me!"
```

How do I encode the "!" character for output?  I tried this:

```
firstNameField.Value = "Me&#33;"
```

But .Net responds with this:

```
<input name="firstNameField" type="text" id="firstNameField" value="Me&amp;#33;" />
```

Causing the user to see `Me&#33;` in the text box.  I understand that this is part of .Net's built-in XSS protection.  How do I get .Net to encode for special characters other than ampersand?

Comment: Is there a problem using `"Me!"`?

Comment: I use "Me!" as an example.  The problem is the `!` and other special characters.  We use Cenzic's Hailstorm to scan our websites for security vulnerabilities.  The newest version of Hailstorm considers un-encoded `!` characters (amongst others) in an input field to be an XSS vulnerability, and thus it rates my website as more insecure than it really is.  In reality, I don't think it's a valid vulnerability, but who knows?  Give hackers the tiniest crack and they'll drive a Mack truck through it.

Comment: In case you don't already use it, here is a link to the ASP.NET AntiXSS library: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814.aspx? It may help you to solve those issues and prevent the Mack truck from crashing into your server.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely consider using AntiXSS in future projects.  Unfortunately for this particular issue, however, exclamation points are on the "safe list" for `AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode()` and are not encoded: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh244070%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up extending the [HttpEncoder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.util.httpencoder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Util;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for CustomHttpEncoder
/// </summary>
public class CustomHttpEncoder : HttpEncoder
{
    //
    // TODO: Add constructor logic here
    //
    public CustomHttpEncoder()
    {
    }

    protected override void HtmlEncode(string value, TextWriter output)
    {
        if (value != null) {
            MyHtmlEncode(value, output);
        }
    }

    protected override void HtmlAttributeEncode(string value, TextWriter output)
    {
        if (value != null) {
            MyHtmlEncode(value, output);
        }
    }

    private void MyHtmlEncode(string value, TextWriter output)
    {
        if (value != null) {
            string encodedValue = "";

            for (int i = 0; i <= value.Length - 1; i++) {
                byte[] asciiVal = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value.Substring(i, 1));
                encodedValue += "&#" + asciiVal(0).ToString + ";";
            }

            output.Write(encodedValue);
        }
    }

}
```

And then referencing it in Web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime encoderType="CustomHttpEncoder" />
```

After that, all I had to do was set the value like normal:

```
firstNameField.Value = "Me!"
```

Which automatically encodes every character for maximum tin-foil hat security:

```
<input name="firstNameField" type="text" id="firstNameField" value="&#77;&#101;&#33;" />
```

This suits my purposes well enough, but I could see it being a PITA in other situations.  In that case, `MyHtmlEncode()` would need to be modified to suit such situations.

Answer (score 0):

Use  HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("text") while assigning the value in code behind

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work.  The HtmlEncode function only encodes these characters `< > ' " &`  It does not encode exclamation points.